# How do I use Google Apps Script to create a Google Calendar event with Hangouts Meet video call attached?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am looking for an example of Google Apps Script in which a new calendar event is created with a Hangouts Meet video conference call attached. For your reference, the most relevant article that I've found to accomplish this is found [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events). I hope that an example will help me understand what the script should look like so that I can reproduce it for my own purposes.

So that there's no misunderstanding, I want to accomplish with Google Apps Script what I would accomplish if I used the "Add conferencing" feature  available when creating a new calendar event manually.

With the video call attached, I hope for attendees to click on the calendar event and see the option to join the Hangouts Meet video call.

Again, I want to accomplish this using Google Apps Script and am looking primarily for an example.

Comment: You can take a look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#creating_events and https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#conferencing

Comment: I have examined those pages (in fact the second one is included in my question). Do you have an example of a function that would create a new calendar event with a video call attached? Perhaps an explanation of each of the parameters required? To add more details, I am able to create the calendar event, but it appears without the video call attached.

Comment: Add your code to the question, it's always a good starting point for asking questions on SO.

Comment: The reason I posted this question without code was because all the code I know about this issue is described in the articles provided. If you'd like though, I can post that code here.

Comment: This code is enough to produce the calendar event.
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-06-12T17:00:00-07:00"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-06-12T09:00:00-07:00"
  },

Comment: To add the video call, I have tried adding
 "hangoutLink": "meet.google.com/zct-bbdf-vei",
 but with no success.

Comment: I have also begun to add "conferenceData": {
    "conferenceId": "zct-bbdf-vei",
}
 but also with no success.
I have added all other related properties such as those under conferenceSolution, createRequest, and entryPoints with different combinations of each. There is no guide provided as to what each property value should be or which ones are required, so I have no idea of knowing what code to write. If you can provide more details about this, such as an example of a function that successfully creates an event with a video call attached, that would be very helpful.

Comment: from [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) for `conferenceData`: To persist your changes, remember to set the **conferenceDataVersion** request parameter to **1** for all event modification requests.

Comment: is this an event modification request? can't i create the calendar event with the video call attached or do i have to create the event and then attach the video call to the already created event?

Comment: okay, i think I got want you were saying. Let me experiment a little more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! This is the code I was looking for.

```
function newEvent() {
  var event = {
    "summary": 'Test',
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2018-06-12T17:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2018-06-12T09:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "conferenceData": {
      "createRequest": {
        "conferenceSolutionKey": {
          "type": "hangoutsMeet"
        },
        "requestId": "kdb-atdx-exx"
      }
    }
  };

  Calendar.Events.insert(event, 'primary', {
    "conferenceDataVersion": 1});
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a link to the article where you found this.

Comment: There is a similar code in https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/94791d48823e9659aa376cf7f0161d9b#gas
I have been struggling with adapting to make it work from data of event details on a sheet. I have as columns the following: Event name, Start time, End time, Attendees. I am looping over the rows to create an event with gmeet link for each row. I want the invite to received by Attendees over email. No luck with setting the argument sendInvites: true.  Also the attendees are many i. e. there are multiple comma separated email addresses in each cell in the column with Attendees. Any pointers?